# jax-ws webservice : unable to add headers to messageContext

Tags: soap, header, jax-ws

---

```
public class MessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
       SOAPMessage msg = messageContext.getMessage();

       Boolean outbound = (Boolean) messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY); 
       if(outbound) { 
           System.out.println("SOAP message departing…"); 
           System.out.println("************** "+messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE));


           MimeHeaders mh = msg.getMimeHeaders();
           mh.setHeader("customer-header", "customer-header");

           Iterator itr3 = mh.getAllHeaders();
           while(itr3.hasNext()) {
               MimeHeader obj = (MimeHeader) itr3.next();
               System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh "+obj.getName());
               System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh "+obj.getValue());
}
```

---

Here is the snippet of code from handleMessage method of my Soap message handler in which I'm trying to add a custom-header to my soap response. Though I'm able to add it to the MimeHeader object however when I invoke the web service the response does not contain that.

One more thing which I noticed is the headers in MimeHeader do not match with the headers which I'm getting in soap response at all. They don't even match with request headers.
I'm using soap UI to invoke my soap service and see the headers.

Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do but you mention request and response headers so this might be what you are after:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);
List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
value.add("customer-header");
headers.put("customer-header", value);
```

MimeHeaders are for headers present in a MIME part of a message when using SOAP attachments and I think you also need a call to [`saveChanges()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#saveChanges%28%29) after that. For usual headers you need to use `MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS`

**EDIT** based on your comment:

> I tried this however since I'm getting a null 'headers' object it throws me null pointer exception when I try to add a custom-header.

It should still be possible to add custom headers to your response even if your implementation returns null. Have you tried something like this instead:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)messageContext.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);

List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
value.add("customer-header");

if (headers != null) {
    headers.put("customer-header", value);
} else {
    Map<String, List<String>> brandNewHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    brandNewHeaders.put("customer-header", value);
    messageContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS, brandNewHeaders);
}
```

Comment: I tried this however since I'm getting a null 'headers' object. It throws me null pointer exception when I try to add a custom-header.

Comment: @Max: I changed my answer in response to you comment. See if it helps.